# how to call the javascript function through ActionFunction?

Tags: visualforce, javascript

In The below code  the submitEmp() method not working can any one tell me how to call the javascript function through the ActionFunction

```
<script> 
function innerJavascript(){ 
alert('Start invoking vf action!');
submitEmp();
}
</script>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public pageReference submitEmp(){
  EMPTest__c c= new EMPTest__c();
  insert c;
  return null;
}
```

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/29975/how-to-change-attribute-value-in-javascript/29981#29981

please have a look for this post, it might help you

Answer (score 3):

I think you're confusing some things. Actionfunctions are to expose controller (apex) methods to javascript. Actionfunctions are not to call javascript methods from apex. You may do well to read the [ActionMethod documentation and examples.](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm)

Though Looking at your included code, it IS what you are looking for:

```
<apex:page controller="myController">
    <script> 
    myActionMethod(); //this is javascript
    </script>
    <apex:form>
            <!-- this is an apex/vf method that will be call-able from JS -->
            <apex:actionFunction name="myActionMethod" 
                                 action="{!submitEmp}" />
             <!-- the action attribute is the apex controller method you want to call -->
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>


public class myController{
    public void submitEmp(){
        EMPTest__c c= new EMPTest__c();
        insert c;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think for [this](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm) post from salesforce has explained apex:actionfunction very well, follow i am trying to explain as what you want:

```
<apex:page standardController="EMPTest__c">

        function innerJavascript() {
           submitEmp();
        }

    </script >
    <apex:form id="form1">
        <apex:actionFunction name="submitEmp" action="{!submitEmp}" rerender="out">
        </apex:actionFunction>
    </apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

Answer (score -1):

It should work like you want.

**VISUALFORCE PAGE**

```
<script> 
  function innerJavascript(){ 
  alert('Start invoking vf action!');
  submitEmp();
}
</script>
...
<apex:form>
  <apex:actionFunction name="submitEmp" action="{!submitEmp}"/>
</apex:form>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public void submitEmp(){
  EMPTest__c c= new EMPTest__c();
  insert c;
}
```

Comment: How does this provide more info than the answers which were already posted ?

Comment: Get a downvote ?? Interesting... Is the answer wrong ?? Please leave your comment for further improving. Thank you the downvoter.

Comment: As per my comment, your answer doesn't really contain different information than the answers that were posted 3 hours before your answer. Does it ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, however, I am not @kumar. And, I just answered his question **directly**, and give him the code just fits the original question. As you asked if it is different.... please, how can I answer it. The following questions you asked, should it be asked to the post owner.

Comment: By the way, it's a technical community, right? I hope to make sure if my answer is wrong or not. I don't really care about downvote. And if the answer I give is wrong, please point it. Thanks again.

Comment: It's not wrong, but it also does not bring extra information compared to the answers already there when you posted or much explanation beyond posting the code. That is why I downvoted. If you feel some minor changes are in order in existing answers, you're better to edit them or comment on them.